# Markdown: continue text in list after a nested list

Tags: list, markdown

I need to insert a sub-list in a list and then continue the text in the item:

```
1. Start of the item text
    - First item of sublist;
    - Second item of sublist;

More text of the first item.

2. Second Item

3. Third item
```

The text after the nested list is not aligned correctly after rendering (should be aligned with "Start", is aligned with "1."). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text should be left-aligned with the text after the number, then the rendered text will be aligned to it.

Here is your example:

```
1. Start of the item text
    - First item of sublist;
    - Second item of sublist;
      
      More text of the sublist of the first item.
The pending text of "More text of the sublist of the first item."

  More text of the first item.
The pending text of "More text of the first item."

2. Second Item

3. Third item
```

The first line text have two chars: `1` `.` with one space   before the text conent `Start of...`

Then the text you wants to aligned should also have **3** spaces       before the text content of `More text of...`

Moreover, having **<=N spaces** (N presents the length of the prefix text of the list context, in this example, N=3) before the text content will make the content aligns with this list text

e.g.
Having **1** ~ **3** spaces will make the text aligns with the 1st line text, having **4** ~ **6** spaces will make the text aligns with the 2nd line text,